# React testing library: How to manage the duplicated test code

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, react-testing-library

Recently i'm working with integration testing from an app which is composed by different components and services, so i'm creating tests for different user behavior interactions with this elements.

The thing that i noticed is that my tests are repeating some common initial statements.

For example:

- There is an initial search input that i need to trigger in order to get list data displayed.

So i always start with the next sentence:

```
beforeEach(() => render(MyComponent))

test('test A', () => {
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /search/i/)))
  // ... rest of the particular test
})

test('test B', () => {
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /search/i/)))
  // ... rest of the particular test
})

test('test C', () => {
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /search/i/)))
  // ... rest of the particular test
})

// and so on...
```

So what i did was create a `fireSearchClick` global function as:

```
const fireSearchClick = () => fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /search/i/)))

test('test A', () => {
  fireSearchClick() // <<< now is called in this way
  // ... rest of the particular test
})
```

I think that this have the advantage that there is only one place to update the "fire search" trigger, for example, if the button label changes to "submit" (just as change example).

But when i continue forward more tests, i end with repeatable patterns like:

```
test('test N', async () => {
  fireSearchClick()

  await loadingData() // another global function that i created for wait results

  fireNextPage() // another global function that i created for go through next page results
  
  await loadingData()

  // the particular things of this test...
})

test('test M', async () => {
  fireSearchClick()

  await loadingData() // another global function that i created for wait results

  fireNextPage() // another global function that i created for go through next page results
  
  await loadingData()

  // the particular things of this test...
})

// and so on...
```

My concern here is:

- Is this a good idea?
- Is there another better way to execute repeatable steps on tests?

I was thinking on implement all the initial repeatable steps on the `beforeEach` hook, but it **maybe** it could contain a lot of logic that will be difficult to track when some of that steps fail (for example, difficult to figure out where is the error if i have failed `fireEvent` executions inside of the `beforeEach`)

What do you think? how do you manage this scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group all the setup in a single function and call it inside your tests or a `beforeEach` hook

```js
const setupTest = async () => {
  render(<MyComponent />)
  fireSearchClick()
  await loadingData()
  fireNextPage()
  await loadingData()
}

test('test M', async () => {
  await setupTest()
  // the particular things of this test...
})
```

However, if this is making the tests too slow and you want to improve the speed, you could try rendering the particular component with the state already setup--ready for your test. i.e.

```js
render(<MyComponent data={mockData} page={2} />)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that both options are a good approaches, probably the second way could be better